# Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException MainActivity.onPostCreate

Tags: java, android

```
04-03 10:19:34.572    2189-2189/com.techexpert4u.duaaadhkaar E/AndroidRuntime﹕ FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.techexpert4u.duaaadhkaar, PID: 2189
    java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.techexpert4u.duaaadhkaar/com.techexpert4u.duaaadhkaar.MainActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException
            at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2195)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2245)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:135)
            at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1196)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5017)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:779)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:595)
            at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
     Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
            at com.techexpert4u.duaaadhkaar.MainActivity.onPostCreate(MainActivity.java:936)
            at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnPostCreate(Instrumentation.java:1150)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2178)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2245)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:135)
            at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1196)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5017)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:779)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:595)
            at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

i NEED HELP ON THIS PLEASE HELP ME.

```
@Override
protected void onPostCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onPostCreate(savedInstanceState);
    // Sync the toggle state after onRestoreInstanceState has occurred.
    mDrawerToggle.syncState();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Given that source and that stack trace, apparently `mDrawerToggle` is `null`.

Comment: @Solaiman If you follow your Stack trace, you'll see that is in line 936. How are you initializing your `mDrawerToggle` object?

Comment: I did that I am still having problem. I posted the code below

Answer (score 0):

The null mDrawerToggle field appears to be supposed to be initialized in your code of initializeDrawer(), but there is no evidence that you ever call that method.

Call initializeDrawer in an onCreate() or otherwise make sure that it happens in any code path *before* you attempt to use mDrawerToggle.

Comment: sorry I didn't quiet understand you because of i am newbie on programing. can you explain little bit more? thanks in advance. do you mean i need to put it in onCreat()

Comment: You never call initializeDrawer(), so you never accomplish the initialization which it was intended to do.  Putting a call to it in onCreate() would indeed be the first idea that comes to mind, but knowing what is best would require knowing a lot more about your program.